# Skype needs two clicks to share desktop

Tags: 11.04, skype

If someone shares their desktop with me using Skype it works fine. If I share my Ubuntu 11.04 desktop with them it is not successful. I stop desktop sharing - then click on the Skype menu to share and on the second click it is successful. Could this be a problem with Compiz? Once desktop is shared it is responsive and fast. I have all the latest updates applied and use HP laptop with NVidia chip

Answer (score 1):

Well, that should be fairly easy to check. If you deactivate compiz and the problem goes away, then it's a problem with Skype and Compiz. If the problem does not go away, then it is just a problem with Skype.